# How used variable parameter instead keywords in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, request, quotes

I have code:

```
    <php
    ...
    $req->setKeywords("mp3");
    ...
    ?>
```

I want use the title of page  the_title() instead mp3 and send it in request.
How can I do that?

Comment: _`the_title()`_... sounds like a Wordpress function. If so, you probably want `$req->setKeywords(get_the_title());`

Comment: Yes! You absolutly right and your solution is working! Thanks! =)